# CREATE TABLE with columns by expanding (and concatenating) a struct in another table

Tags: sql, struct, hive

`table1` has the structure:

```
DESCRIBE table1;
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  col_name   |                              data_type                                 |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| key         | string                                                                 |
| source      | string                                                                 |
| address     | struct<address:string,zip:string,city:string,state:string,cntry:string>|
| column4     | date                                                                   |
| column5     | date                                                                   | 
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The first two lines of `table1` are:

```
SELECT * FROM db.table1 limit 2;
+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+------------+--+
| key  | source   |                                         address                                     | column4            | column5    |
+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+------------+--+
| 001  | internet | {"address":" 123 FAKE ST","zip":"12345","city":"MIAMI","state":"FL","cntry":"USA"}  | 2007-01-27         | 2009-12-12 |
| 002  | internet | {"address":" 234 FAKE ST","zip":"23456","city":"MIAMI","state":"FL","cntry":"USA"}  | 2012-03-23         | 2014-01-30 |
+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+------------+--+
```

I want to create a new `table2` wherein I copy `table1`'s information, but expand out the struct in the `address` column into its five constituent columns (`address`, `zip`, `city`, `state`, `cntry`) and then make a column that's a concatenation of `address` and `zip`.

I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS 
(
    SELECT 
           key, source, 
           address.address, address.zip, address.city, address.state, address.cntry,
           CONCAT(address.address, ' ', address.zip), 
           column4, column5 
    FROM 
           db.table1
);
```

But that gave me the error `Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:35 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'key' in select clause (state=42000,code=40000)`

`table2` should have the structure:

```
DESCRIBE table2;
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  col_name   |                              data_type                                 |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| key         | string                                                                 |
| source      | string                                                                 |
| address     | string                                                                 |
| zip         | string                                                                 |
| city        | string                                                                 |
| state       | string                                                                 |
| cntry       | string                                                                 |
| add_zip     | string                                                                 |
| column4     | date                                                                   |
| column5     | date                                                                   | 
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And contain all of the data from `table1`.

To be frank, I am not sure if this is the proper way to go about splitting out this struct, so any help would be very useful.

Comment: Can we see your table data for both tables

Comment: @SolaOshinowo I have added the data for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is a bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword.  Apparently, the parentheses are causing the issue.  Also, you are missing a column name for the computed column.

Does this work?

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS 
    SELECT key, source, 
           address.address, address.zip, address.city, address.state, address.cntry,
           CONCAT(address.address, ' ', address.zip) as address_zip, 
           column4, column5 
    FROM db.table1;
```